# Using wlan1 instead of wlan0 in Android Nexus 6

Tags: wi-fi, adb, networking, kernel

I am trying to use a WiFi dongle with Android Nexus 6 with custom ROM and kernel. I have installed drivers of USB WiFi dongle on Android phone that appears at wlan1 network interface in adb shell. Whereas, the default WiFi appears at wlan0. However, I am unable to access or even ping the devices available on wlan1.

I have connected the USB dongle to it's WiFi and assigned an IP address:

```
iw dev wlan1 connect -w WiFi-XC
ip addr add 172.16.0.120/16 broadcast 172.16.255.255 dev wlan1
```

The dmesg show that the association to the WiFi AP is successful:

```
[  242.667204] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan1: link is not ready
[  245.599269] wlan1: authenticate with 70:b3:d5:95:94:6e
[  245.599934] wlan1: send auth to 70:b3:d5:95:94:6e (try 1/3)
[  245.603278] wlan1: authenticated
[  245.604767] wlan1: associate with 70:b3:d5:95:94:6e (try 1/3)
[  245.606292] wlan1: RX AssocResp from 70:b3:d5:95:94:6e (capab=0x421 status=0 aid=2)
[  245.609720] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan1: link becomes ready
[  245.616657] wlan1: associated
```

The routing table looks like:

```
10.10.0.0/16 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.10.108 
172.16.0.0/16 dev wlan1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.0.120
```

Whereas, the output of ifconfig looks like:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:80:eb:30:e5:03
          inet addr:10.10.10.108  Bcast:10.10.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0 
          inet6 addr: fe80::4680:ebff:fe30:e503/64 Scope: Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3670 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:4500 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:854154 TX bytes:1080264 
wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:b3:d5:95:85:f1  Driver wifidongle
          inet addr:172.16.0.120  Bcast:172.16.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0 
          inet6 addr: fe80::72b3:d5ff:fe95:85f1/64 Scope: Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:487 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:29 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:30055 TX bytes:6051
```

When I try to ping the router at 172.16.0.10, or ping the device from router, the ping doesn't succeed. However, when I try to run `nmap -sn 172.16.0.0/24` on the router to see the devices it can see, surprisingly it shows that it can see the device:

```
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-07-11 12:56 UTC
Nmap scan report for 172.16.0.120
Host is up (0.0017s latency).
```

I have a suspicion that both wlan0 and wlan1 cannot work at the same time. If this is the case, how can I take down wlan0. If this is not the case and both wlan0 and wlan1 can work at the same time, can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: You are looking at only main table in routing table. Android uses many other tables as well, particularly 97.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments, there are multiple routing tables that Android uses. The routing table that is shown by `ip route show` is the main routing table, which is not added to ip rule list by default in android. Do add the main routing table to ip rule, you need to execute command `ip rule add from all lookup main pref 1`.